# How can you get charged creeper spawners without any external programmes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been searching everywhere (mainly on youtube) for ages, but I cannot find any tutorials on how to get charged creeper spawners without either MCEdit or NBTEdit. Is there a way to get charged creeper spawners without the use of external programs?

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're on creative with cheats enabled and on version 1.7, you should be able to place down a command block and insert this command into it:

`/setblock ~ ~ ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:Creeper,SpawnData:{powered:1}}`

Then power with any redstone device, and the command block should turn into a charged creeper spawner.

Comment: Thhanks loads. That is the most helpful answer I have ever had. In returb, I will give you a cool command. The command is: /summon FallingSand ~ ~100 ~ {TileID:8,Time:1} Enter this correctly and you should get a wet surprise.

Comment: The other answers were just telling you it wouldn't work :) Cool command. Did my command work for you?

Comment: yes it does. I have worked out how to convert it to make spawners like angry wolf spawners and tamedocelot spawners.

Comment: Ooh! How? Especially the tamed ocelots.

Comment: The tamed ocelot spawners: /setblock ~ ~ ~ {Owner:<username here>,CatType:<1,2 or 3>}

Comment: cat type 1 is black, cat type 2 is ginger and cat type 3 is tabby/grey

Comment: tamed wolf spawner: /setblock ~ ~ ~ {Owner:<username here>}

Comment: wither skeleton spawners: /setblock ~ ~ ~ {SkeletonType:1}

Comment: do not forget the minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace and EntityId: and SpawnData:

Comment: And finally the tnt spawner: /setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:PrimedTnt,SpawnData:{Fuse:120}}

Comment: You could've grouped all of that into one comment for efficiency. :) You know, you don't need the "minecraft:" -- I've always just done mob_spawner, cooked_beef, planks, etc... no minecraft:planks involved.

Comment: You may wish to move extended discussions into chat for ease and to save space for comments pertaining to the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

Spawners? No.  You can't even get standard creeper spawners.  The only way to get a charged creeper 100% in vanilla without an external editor or mod is to have a creeper struck by lightning.  Obviously, even in perfect conditions, this is hard to accomplish, and won't produce a steady stream of them like a dungeon spawner will for other mobs.

Of course the above only applies to survival without cheats.  In creative mode (or any mode with cheats enabled), you can get a charged creeper or even a spawner.  This is because you can assign NBT tags to a block or entity using the `/setblock` or `/summon` command, respectively.

<sup>(Note that I don't know the exact commands it would take to make this work.  I'll do some research, but if someone wants to edit it in, feel free.)</sup>

Comment: It's also possible in the latest versions using the "Summon" command. "/summon Creeper ~ ~1 ~ {powered:1}" will spawn a powered creeper at your location. (Or the location of a command block if the command is called through that)

Comment: I totally didn't think about that, thanks.

Answer (score -4):

Do you mean without mods? No you can't only single screeners get supercharged with lightning